# Mapping one (entity class) to many (dto's/viewModels)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper, ef-code-first

I am trying to map information about the User to several dto's, but I'm getting null exceptions. Basically, the reason why I distributed the information among several classes is because there are common info that I need in several views. So this is what I ended up with:

**User entity class**

```
public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public float Credits { get; set; }
    public float PromotionalCredits { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public double RatingAverage { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImage { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CreditCard> CreditCard { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> ReceivedMessages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> SentMessages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> WatchList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rating> OwnRatings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rating> RatingsForOthers { get; set; }
 }
```

**DTO's and ViewModel calsses**

```
public class UserInfoSummaryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public UserDetailedStatus DetailedStatus { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetailedStatus
{
    public float TotalCredits { get; set; }
    public float Credits { get; set; }
    public float PromotionalCredits { get; set; }
    public BiddingAndItems BiddingAndItems { get; set; }
    public int OngoingListings { get; set; }
    public int NewMessages { get; set; }
    public float Rating { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfRatings { get; set; }
}

public class BiddingAndItems
{
    public int TotalBids { get; set; }
    public int WinningBids { get; set; }
    public int AcquiredItems { get; set; }
    public int ItemsAwaitingConfirmation { get; set; }
    public List<ItemForUserBids> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Mappings inside AutoMapperBootStrapper class**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, BiddingAndItems>()
                .ForMember(m => m.TotalBids, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.TotalActiveBids()))
                .ForMember(m=>m.ItemsAwaitingConfirmation, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.Items.Count(i=>i.IsAwaitingReceptionConfirmation().Equals(true))))
                .ForMember(m=>m.AcquiredItems, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.AquiredItems().Count))
                .ForMember(m => m.WinningBids,
                           o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Bids.Where(c => c.Item.CurrentHighestBidderId().Equals(s.Id))));

            Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDetailedStatus>()
                .ForMember(m => m.NumberOfRatings, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.OwnRatings.Count()))
                .ForMember(m => m.NewMessages, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.TotalUnreadMessages()))
                .ForMember(m => m.OngoingListings, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Items.Where(i => i.IsPublished())))
                .ForMember(m => m.Rating, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.RatingAverage))
                .ForMember(m => m.TotalCredits, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.TotalCredits()));

            Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserInfoSummaryViewModel>();
```

**Call to automapper inside UserController**

```
    public ActionResult Summary()
    {

        var user = _helper.GetUserFromSession();
        var viewModel = Mapper.Map<User, UserInfoSummaryViewModel>(user);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I thought because I have all the necessary mappings inside the bootstrapper this should, *theoretically* work, apparently I was wrong... How can I fix that?

**UPDATE:**

I got my mappings fixed and added a couple of value resolvers. Now I'm not getting a null reference exception but there seems to be something wrong because everytime I run the project it gets stuck and then the local server stops responding... Here's my code:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<User, BiddingAndItems>()
            .ForMember(m => m.TotalBids, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.TotalActiveBids()))
            .ForMember(m => m.ItemsAwaitingConfirmation,
                       o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Items.Count(i => i.IsAwaitingReceptionConfirmation().Equals(true))))
            .ForMember(m => m.AcquiredItems, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.AquiredItems().Count))
            .ForMember(m => m.WinningBids, o => o.ResolveUsing<WinningBidsResolver>())
            .ForMember(m => m.Items, o => o.ResolveUsing<BiddingItemResolver>());

        Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDetailedStatus>()
            .ForMember(m => m.NumberOfRatings, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.OwnRatings.Count()))
            .ForMember(m => m.NewMessages, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.TotalUnreadMessages()))
            .ForMember(m => m.OngoingListings, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Items.Where(i => i.IsPublished()).Count()))
            .ForMember(m => m.Rating, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.RatingAverage))
            .ForMember(m=>m.BiddingAndItems, o => o.MapFrom(s=> s))
            .ForMember(m => m.TotalCredits, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.TotalCredits()));

        Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserInfoSummaryViewModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.DetailedStatus, o => o.MapFrom(s => s));

public class BiddingItemResolver : ValueResolver<User, List<ItemForUserBids>>
{
    protected override List<ItemForUserBids> ResolveCore(User source)
    {
        var items = new List<ItemForUserBids>();
        foreach (var bid in source.Bids)
        {
            var item = bid.Item;
            var c = new ItemForUserBids
                        {
                            BidValue = bid.Amount,
                            Description = item.Description,
                            Id = item.Id,
                            ItemThumb = item.MainImageLink(),
                            Status = source.ItemBiddingStatus(item.Id),
                            TimeLeft = TimeUtility.TimeLeft(item.EndDate),
                            Title = item.Title
                        };
            items.Add(c);
        }
        return items;
    }
}

public class WinningBidsResolver : ValueResolver<User, int>
{
    protected override int ResolveCore(User source)
    {
        return source.Bids.Where(c => c.Item.CurrentHighestBidderId().Equals(source.Id)).Count();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm not getting any exceptions to give me any hints about what's going wrong... It just gets stuck! I suspect that my mappings are going into some sort of an infinite loops or something, but I am not sure what is happening exactly... Is there any way I could debug this problem?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information about the exception you receive I can only guess what could go wrong: I *guess* it's because you're using Linq on uninitialized collections in  `MapFrom`. Try implementing a `ValueResolver` instead.

Comment: I've updated my post, please check it out... Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a compiling code example/reproduction (f.e. a console application). I tried pasting your code above into a new project and it didn't compile.

Comment: If your web application does not respond, did you code an endless loop? Did you try the mapping in an isolated context (without a web application or in a unit testing scenario)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. When I first started working on the project, I used to think TDD is a waste of time. But after going through some issues with the project, I finally realized how important unit tests are... the hard way! It is going to be very hard to re-produce my code inside a console application, I guess creating a unit test would be the easy way out although I have a very basic knowledge about unit testing.

Comment: Ok after debugging the application, I confirmed the problem is not caused by the mappings and all this code... It has something to do with my Login action method... Thanks for the help Alexander, I'll open another thread with the issue.